# Firebase Messages get count badge The Unread new Messages Recived

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

**I use Firebase to send messages between users, and I'd like to use a new unread message badge and the number of unread messages.**

**I want to help solve this problem so I can get the number of unread messages when they are received from the other user and displayed in the user's list**

like this  [image]

```
    public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static  final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    public static  final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;
    Typeface MR,MRR;


    private Context mContext;
    private List<Chat> mChat;
    private String imageurl;
public View view_click;
    FirebaseUser fuser;

    public MessageAdapter(Context mContext, List<Chat> mChat, String imageurl){
        this.mChat = mChat;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;

        MRR = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/myriadregular.ttf");
        MR = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/myriad.ttf");

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, false);
            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_left, parent, false);
            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chat chat = mChat.get(position);
        holder.show_message.setTypeface(MRR);

                        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                                                       chat.setSelected(!chat.isSelected());

                                                       holder.view.setBackgroundColor(chat.isSelected() ? Color.TRANSPARENT : Color.WHITE);



                                                       FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://pineka-social-media-mast-da52a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
                                                       ).getReference("Chats")
                                                               .child(chat.getChatid())
                                                               .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                                                           @Override
                                                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                   View view;

                                                                   final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(holder.lyt_parent, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                                                   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                                                   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snack_delete, null);

                                                                   snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                                                   Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarView = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
                                                                   snackBarView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                                                                   snackBarView.addView(view, 0);

                                                                   snackbar.show();


                                                                   // Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted! ="+chat.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                               }
                                                           }
                                                       });





                                                       return false;
                                                   }
                                               });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view_click) {
            //    holder.delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.po);
                LinearLayout copy = dialog.findViewById(R.id.copy);
                LinearLayout share = dialog.findViewById(R.id.share);
                LinearLayout reply = dialog.findViewById(R.id.reply);
                LinearLayout delete = dialog.findViewById(R.id.remove_item);
                copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", chat.getMessage());
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);




                        View view;

                        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(holder.lyt_parent, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snack, null);

                        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarView = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
                        snackBarView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                        snackBarView.addView(view, 0);
                        snackbar.show();








                        dialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });
                share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {




                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(); intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent2.setType("text/plain");
                        intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, chat.getMessage() );
                         mContext. startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent2, "Share via"));
                        dialog.dismiss();



                    }
                });
                reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {




                    }
                });

                delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view_click) {


                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://pineka-social-media-mast-da52a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
                        ).getReference("Chats")
                                .child(chat.getChatid())
                                .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    View view;

                                    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(holder.lyt_parent, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snack_delete, null);

                                    snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarView = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
                                    snackBarView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                                    snackBarView.addView(view, 0);
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                    snackbar.show();


                                   // Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted! ="+chat.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });




                    }
                });
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.show();


/*



 */


            }

        }

        );

        holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());
        if(chat.getTime()!=null && !chat.getTime().trim().equals("")) {
            holder.time_tv.setText(holder.convertTime(chat.getTime()));
        }

        if (imageurl.equals("default")){
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile_outline_40);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

        if (position == mChat.size()-1){
            if (chat.isIsseen()){
           //    holder.seen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_24);

            } else {
           //    holder.seen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_24_read);

            }
        } else {
         // holder.seen.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChat.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView show_message;
        public ImageView profile_image,seen,delete;
        public TextView time_tv;
        public Dialog myDialog;
        public View view_click;
        public LinearLayout lyt_parent;
        private View view;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            show_message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_message);
            profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            time_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_tv);
            seen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seen);
            view = itemView;

            lyt_parent= itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);

        }

        public String convertTime(String time){
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(time)));
            return dateString;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (mChat.get(position).getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        } else {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }



}
```

**item Uaer Massage**

```
public class UserAdaptermsg extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdaptermsg.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    private boolean ischat;
    private OnItemClick onItemClick;

    Typeface MR,MRR;
    String theLastMessage;
     boolean isopend  ;

    public UserAdaptermsg(Context mContext, OnItemClick onItemClick, List<User> mUsers, boolean ischat){
        this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
        this.mUsers = mUsers;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.ischat = ischat;

        if(mContext!=null) {
            MRR = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/myriadregular.ttf");
            MR = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/myriad.ttf");
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item_msg, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final User user = mUsers.get(position);
       // holder.username.setTypeface(MR);
        holder.last_msg.setTypeface(MRR);
        holder.badg_massage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.username.setText(user.getFullname());
        if (user.getImageurl().equals("default")){
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile_outline_40);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageurl()).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

        if (ischat){
            lastMessage(user.getId(), holder.last_msg);
            count(user.getId(),true);
          //  holder.badg_massage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          //  holder.badg_massage.setText(mUsers.size()+"");

        } else {
            holder.last_msg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (ischat){
            if (user.getStatus().equals("online")){
                holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }




            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MessageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userid", user.getId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        holder.profile_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               onItemClick.onItemCLick(user.getId(),view);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView username;
        public ImageView profile_image;
        private ImageView img_on;
        private ImageView img_off;
        private TextView last_msg;
        private TextView badg_massage;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            img_on = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_on);
            img_off = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_off);
            last_msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_msg);
            badg_massage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.badg_massage);
        }
    }

    //check for last message
    private void lastMessage(final String userid, final TextView last_msg){
        theLastMessage = "default";
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                   if (firebaseUser != null && chat != null) {
                        if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                                chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                            theLastMessage = chat.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }

                switch (theLastMessage){
                    case  "default":
                        last_msg.setText("No Message");
                        break;

                    default:
                        last_msg.setText(theLastMessage);

                        break;
                }

                theLastMessage = "default";
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void count(final String userid, final Boolean count){
        isopend = false;
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if (firebaseUser != null && chat != null) {
                        if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                                chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                            isopend = chat.isIsopened();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isopend == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "notopent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "isopend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                isopend = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }





}
```

**model Chat**

```
package com.Model;

public class Chat {

    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String message;
    private boolean isseen;
    private String chatid;
    private boolean isSelected = false;
    private boolean isopened;



    private String time;

    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message, boolean isseen, String chatid, boolean isopened, String time) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
        this.isseen = isseen;
        this.chatid = chatid;
        this.isopened = isopened;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Chat() {
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean isIsseen() {
        return isseen;
    }

    public void setIsseen(boolean isseen) {
        this.isseen = isseen;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getChatid() {
        return chatid;
    }

    public void setChatid(String chatid) {
        this.chatid = chatid;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isIsopened() {
        return isopened;
    }

    public void setIsopened(boolean isopened) {
        this.isopened = isopened;
    }
}
```

Comment: put only relevant information so it can be easy to understand what you asking for. because you haven't clearly asked what you want to do and where you are stuck or what is not working.

Comment: put only params of chat class remove getter and setter no need to display here. every developer will understand automatically getter and setter. also, put your firebase schema here so it can be easy to understand what's going on.

Comment: Your approach to getting an unread count is a little costly to your firebase project. instead of getting every chat message and counting unread by the status of the message, you can increase the unread count when a user sends a new message and decrease the unread count when a user reads the message.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600 (six hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.